# How can I show that (A−B)−(B−C)=(A−B)?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm stuck in this step, can someone show me how to complete the proof with each step name?
[image]

Comment: To format the formulas, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation); also [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21258/139123) for the specific format of your equations.

Comment: By the way, $(A \setminus B) \setminus (B \setminus C) = A \setminus B$ is a set identity. There, we're done. Oh ... you need to prove it with set identities you've previously found or have been given. We don't know which identities those are. Do you have an identity $X \cup (X\cap Y) = X$?

Comment: yes Distribution law

Answer (score 2):

You have $(B \setminus C) \subset B$, so $(A \setminus B) \cap (B \setminus C) =\emptyset$, so $(A \setminus B) \setminus (B \setminus C) = A \setminus B$.

Comment: thank you so much, but I need to solve it using set identities

Comment: Aren't that set identities ?...

Answer (score 1):

Distribute and conclude like this $=(A\cap\underbrace{\bar B\cap \bar B}_{=\bar B})\cup(\underbrace{A\cap\bar B\cap C}_{\subset \ A\cap\bar B})=A\cap\bar B=A-B$

By using $(F\subset E)\implies E\cup F=E$.